# Can't run embedded Tomcat with Gradle

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, build.gradle, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying to run embedded Tomcat with gradle, everything looks good, but when i am executing tomcatRunWar task this task running into console and nothing is going on.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.5'
}
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
def tomcatVersion = '7.0.59'
tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
}

dependencies {Other dependencies}
```

[image: Running all time and never ends]

If deploy generated war into Tomcat manually It works great

Comment: The plugin deploys the WAR file but keeps the embedded Tomcat container running until you shut it down via CTRL + C. What exactly did you expect to happen?

Comment: OMG, really. It works, i just expected to see executed task and console. Can I see log information into embedded tomcat?

Comment: The executed task is shown. Any logging from your application will be rendered to the console (it might be in a different tab in your IDE). I don't think the embedded Tomcat instance renders all other information you'd normally see in a standalone Tomcat instance.